# What is the radius of convergence for $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{i^{j}+(-i)^{j}-i}{j!}z^{j}?$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

How do I find the radius of convergence for

\begin{equation}
\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{i^{j}+(-i)^{j}-i}{j!}z^{j}
\end{equation}

At first I thought I could do some simplification using the fact that $i^{3}=-i$, and then using the ratio test, but I wasn't able to get anywhere from there. Should I instead use some kind of bound?

Answer (score 1):

You could notice that the modulus of the numerator is bounded between two constants, so applying the formula for the radius of convergence reduces to take the $n$-th root of $n!$ and evaluate the limit to $+\infty$.

Comment: It doesn't seems to me that it reaches zero, but I haven't done the calculation properly. Anyway, it isn't a real problem, given that it doesn't change the result (cause we are actually evaluating a limsup of the $n$-th root of the coefficients).